# Where to find offline installer for Vaadin 7?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, vaadin

I'm working with Vaadin 7, Eclipse(Juno) and Java EE 7.

I want to use the Eclipse Vaadin plugin to create *and* compile Vaadin projects. The problem is that the Vaadin plugin insists on checking the vaadin website for updates before doing just about anything (and crashes my eclipse when it can't do it) - I am behind a very restrictive network and cannot use it in this way.

I found this: https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/vaadin-plug-in-for-eclipse 
Which is a downloadable offline repo for Vaadin *6*, and it works fine, but there is no alternative offline repo for Vaadin *7* - which is the version I must use.

Short of manually downloading all of the .jar files, manually adding them to each project I create, and compiling the widgetsets for each composite by hand (which I assume is possible) how can I get Vaadin 7 up and running, considering my very restrictive network?

Comment: You either use maven to handle your dependencies (This is what the eclipse plugin does) or you download every single jar step by step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think thats what you search for:
https://vaadin.com/download#direct-download

Comment: Thanks! When I asked this question (a year ago) that unfortunately wasn't available... but I suppose this is still the right answer.