# Error .gwt.xml Vaadin

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, gwt, vaadin

**UPDATE:**
I was able to add Vaadin 7 jars manually and create a v7 application but it still grave me the same error in the xml when I run it

I'm new to Vaadin and web application development. I'm still wrapping my head around all that is envolved in this technology and how it works.

I wanna develop a simple application with a login to do basic file parsing. I downloaded the Vaadin 6 eclipse plugin (I wasn't able to use version 7 because of newtork security). I'm using Tomcat 7, Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2, as well as Apache IvyDe plugin (which I still don't understand what it does!)

I used the dragDrop wizard in Vaadin to create the interface of my Login page but when I tried to run my program it it gave me the following error

```
The errors below were detected when validating the file "gwt-module.dtd" via the file "LoginWidgetset.gwt.xml".  
In most cases these errors can be detected by validating "gwt-module.dtd" directly.
However it is possible that errors will only occur when gwt-module.dtd is validated in the context of LoginWidgetset.gwt.xml.

Line 2 - The markup declarations contained by the document type decleration must be well-formed
```

and there seem to be an error in the LoginWidgetset.gwt.xml which I couldn't reslove

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 1.7.0//EN"
 "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">

<module>
<inherits name="com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.DefaultWidgetSet" />

<!--
 Uncomment the following to compile the widgetset for one browser only.
 This can reduce the GWT compilation time significantly when debugging.
 The line should be commented out before deployment to production
 environments.

 Multiple browsers can be specified for GWT 1.7 as a comma separated
 list. The supported user agents at the moment of writing were:
 ie6,ie8,gecko,gecko1_8,safari,opera

 The value gecko1_8 is used for Firefox 3 and later and safari is used for
 webkit based browsers including Google Chrome.
-->
<set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8"/>
</module>
```

I was also trying to use one of the Addons from the official Vaadin website but whenever I run my appliation it gives me the same error with the .gwt.xml

Does anybody know what's causing this error? It would also be very helpful if you could explain to me the role of the IvyDe plugin. I'm not using Maven but only because I don't know how it would help. If you could shed a light on that too I'd really appreciate it.

And on a final note, is this the right approach I should be taking to develop web apps or should I stick with common frameworks and jsp?

Thanks

Comment: I strongly suggest do use vaadin 7.

Comment: I would! Only that the only offline eclipse plugin release is the 6. And I can't bypass network security to be able to use 7. Although this error is not related to the version number, I tried the Addons for version 6 and they still didn't work

Comment: Specifying it here should work http://vaadin.com/eclipse. What network security issues do you have?

Comment: That was my first attempt before using the offline plugin. It's a very restrective network. For more details I found this user has the same problem as me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990899/where-to-find-offline-installer-for-vaadin-7

Comment: You either use maven to handle your dependencies (This is what the eclipse plugin does) or you download every single jar step by step. (Perhaps you can download the required repos manually at home and then move them to your dev system?)

Comment: So I downloaded the seprate jar files for vaadin 7 and followed the instruction (copying them to WEB-INF/lib folder after that I copyied the client and the client complier to a lib folder I created in my project path directory and recomplied the project after I added one of the addons from the website) I was able to use elements from the 7 framework which was great but I still got the same error with the widgetset

Answer (score 0):

The network security was blocking the google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com server so I created a gwt-module.dtd and stored it to a local directory and then referenced that in my xml instead of the live link.

```
<!DOCTYPE module 
SYSTEM "file:\\\\public\share\MyWebApp\WebContent\WEB-INF\gwt-module.dtd">
```